# Failure sending message in smtp/The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, azure, smtp

I'm trying to do a reset password and recover password function. Therefore i used the smtp way to send the mail. However, i got an error from my try catch.

```
Error Occured: Failure sending mail.
```

I'm also not sure which part of my web.config file should i add this connection code

```
<network host="smtp.gmail.com" enableSsl="true"  />
```

Below is my connection to my Azure database while having the smtp logic.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uniqueCode = string.Empty;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            // get the records matching the supplied username or email id.         
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from MemberAccount where nric COLLATE Latin1_general_CS_AS=@nric or email COLLATE Latin1_general_CS_AS=@email", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nric", Convert.ToString(txtUserName.Text.Trim()));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Convert.ToString(txtEmailId.Text.Trim()));
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.Dispose();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dr.Read();
                //generate unique code
                uniqueCode = Convert.ToString(System.Guid.NewGuid());
                //Updating an unique random code in then UniquCode field of the database table
                cmd = new SqlCommand("update MemberAccount set UniqueCode=@uniqueCode where nric=@nric or email=@email", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniqueCode", uniqueCode);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nric", txtUserName.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmailId.Text.Trim());

                StringBuilder strBody = new StringBuilder();
                //Passing emailid,username and generated unique code via querystring. For testing pass your localhost number and while making online pass your domain name instead of localhost path.
                strBody.Append("<a href=http://sipolice.azurewebsites.net/MemberRecoverPassword.aspx" + txtEmailId.Text + "&uName=" + txtUserName.Text + "&uCode=" + uniqueCode + ">Click here to change your password</a>");
                // sbody.Append("&uCode=" + uniqueCode + "&uName=" + txtUserName.Text + ">Click here to change your password</a>");

                System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("SenderEmailIAddress@hotmail.com", dr["email"].ToString(), "Reset Your Password", strBody.ToString());
                //pasing the Gmail credentials to send the email
                System.Net.NetworkCredential mailAuthenticaion = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("SenderEmailIAddress@hotmail.com", "SenderPassword");

                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailclient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.hotmail.com", 587);

                mailclient.EnableSsl = true;
                mailclient.Credentials = mailAuthenticaion;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailclient.Send(mail);
                dr.Close();
                dr.Dispose();
                cmd.ExecuteReader();
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Close();
                lblStatus.Text = "Reset password link has been sent to your email address";
                txtEmailId.Text = string.Empty;
                txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Please enter valid email address or username";
                txtEmailId.Text = string.Empty;
                txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
                con.Close();
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Error Occured: " + ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

***UPDATE***
I just realized why it couldn't work. It did not work as my account information is incorrect

Comment: Can you give us the stacktrace from the error instead of the message? or just the complete exception. Including exception type etc.

Comment: may i ask how to get the stacktrace from the error?

Comment: try
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\output.txt", ex.ToString());
}

Comment: i received this error Access to the path 'C:\output.txt' is denied.

Comment: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), "output.txt"), ex.ToString());` And make sure your asp.net site has an `App_Data` folder before executing.

Answer (score 0):

Why this much blah blah codes. Just Try in Simple way.,

***For Example:***

***In your Web.Config / App.Config:***

```
      <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
          <smtp from="Your Email ID">
            <network host="Your Host Namecom" defaultCredentials="false" password="*********" userName="Your User Name"  enableSsl="true" />
          </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
      </system.net>
```

***In Your Code Behind:***

```
        private void SendMail(string Address, string Body)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                mailMessage.To.Add(Address);
                mailMessage.Subject = "Your Subject";
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.Body = Body;
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(); // This will take the Credentioals from the WEB/APP Config 
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Extention.Log(ex.Message + "/=> " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

***Call the Function Like this:***

```
SendMail("To Address Email Id", strBody.ToString());
```

*It Will work :)*

Comment: Seems a little too simple for me IMO. Because i have to check my database and query it even before i send any email.

Answer (score 0):

I see in your code that you use the hotmail smtp. For my website I also use that server.

If you use those server you must know that your credentials are your hotmail login. The sender of the message must also be the same adres.

I wrote a quick script to send mail and tested it. It worked:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25))
{
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("example@hotmail.com", "******");
    client.EnableSsl = true;

    var from = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("example@hotmail.com", "Your name");
    var to = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("target@example.com", "Receiver name");

    var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);
    message.Subject = "Test mail";
    message.Body = "Content";
    client.Send(message);
}
```

If you specify all your SMTP information in code you do not need it in your web.config.

---

**Microsoft smtp (hotmail/live/outlook etc)**

> **Host:** smtp.live.com
>   **Port:** 587 or if 587 is blocked 25
>   **TSL/SSL:** yes
>   **Authentication:** Your hotmail/live/outlook account
>   **Sender:** Always your hotmail/live/outlook adress

**Gmail smtp**

> **Host:** smtp.gmail.com
>   **Port:** 465
>   **TSL/SSL:** yes
>   **Authentication:** Your gmail account
>   **Sender:** Always your gmail adress

Comment: I did not specify my smtp information. From my code, i have to check and query my database and see if the username matches before even sending off any message.

Comment: You did specify your smtp information: your `mailAuthenticaion` contains your hotmail adres, and your `mailclient` contains your hotmail smtp adres.

Comment: is the smtp configuration code the same for gmail and hotmail? but how and which part of my code should i use to replace it with yours?